# <p:blockUI> doesn't show up on second click of <p:menuitem>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I click to menuitem with id "menuItemId" first time, blockUI is working good but when I click to menuitem again It is not working. Is there any idea?

By the way there are tabs in my content and if user clicks "menuItemId" then tab1 renders, if user clicks "menuItemId2" then tab2 renders and tab1 disappers.

Here is my full page layout;

```
</p:layout>
....
<p:layoutUnit id="centerLayoutUnit" position="center" style="border: none">                
            <ui:insert name="content">Put default content here, if any.</ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
```

My index page;

```
<ui:define name="west">
            <h:form id="westForm">
               <p:panelMenu style="width:200px">
                    <p:submenu label="createUser">
                        <p:menuitem id="menuItemId" ..../>
                        <p:menuitem id="menuItemId2"..../>
                <p:blockUI block=":centerLayoutUnit" trigger="menuItemId">  
                    Loading<br />
                    <p:graphicImage library="images" name="loading.gif"/>  
                </p:blockUI>
            </h:form> 
        </ui:define>
      <ui:define name="content">                 
            <p:panel id="contentPanel">                  
                <p:tabView id="tabView" activeIndex="#{myController.activeIndex}" widgetVar="tabViewWidget">

                  <p:tab title="tab1" rendered="#{myController.tabRenders.get('renderPanel1')}">
                        <ui:include src="createUser.xhtml"/>                            
                    </p:tab>

                  <p:tab title="tab2" rendered="#{myController.tabRenders.get('renderPanel2')}">
                        <ui:include src="createManager.xhtml"/>                            
                    </p:tab>
               </p:tabView>  
            </p:panel> 
        </ui:define>
```

Comment: Can you share `myController.tabRenders.get('')` method?

Comment: @herry It just returns true or false. Program works fine but blockUI component doesn't works second time.

Comment: What is the scope of your bean?

Comment: @miroslav_mijajlovic all beans have "view" scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the trigger not working correctly.

Can you try to manually trigger it? Not tested this code! Please try it!

```
<p:panelMenu style="width:200px">
                    <p:submenu label="createUser">
                        <p:menuitem id="menuItemId" onclick="bui.show()" oncomplete="bui.hide()"..../>
                        <p:menuitem id="menuItemId2" onclick="bui.show()" oncomplete="bui.hide()"..../>
                <p:blockUI block=":centerLayoutUnit" widgetVar="bui">  
                    Loading<br />
                    <p:graphicImage library="images" name="loading.gif"/>  
                </p:blockUI>
```

Comment: Yes manually trigger works fine. But I don't get why my code doesn't works :S